# Error en clave foránea. El enlace es 0 (nulo). MySQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

Haciendo la relación entre el id de un producto (desde la tabla *productos*) a la clave foránea, *idproductos* (de la tabla *descripciones*), no hay ningún error aparente, pero al agregar datos a las columnas, la columna del id relacional muestra un 0 (no hay relación), lo he intentado ya varias veces eliminando ya agregar datos; sí funciona la instrucción **ON DELETE CASCADE** (aunque si elimino una fila, se eliminan todas las de descripciones

El código con el que realicé la relación.

```
ALTER TABLE `inventario`.`descripción` 
ADD INDEX `fk_desprod_idx` (`idproductos` ASC) ;

ALTER TABLE `inventario`.`descripción` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_desprod`
FOREIGN KEY (`idproductos`)
REFERENCES `inventario`.`productos` (`id`)
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

[image: Imagen de una fila en phpmyadmin]

Comment: Actualización: El que al eliminar una fila se eliminen todas de la tabla de descripciones, es porque utilizo la instrucción *("DELETE FROM descripción WHERE idproductos=:idproductos");*. Es decir, va a eliminar los que contengan el mismo id, todos tienen 0.

Answer (score 2):

Donde tienes que crear el índice es en la tabla `productos`, no en `descripción`. El campo `idproductos` ya queda indexado al crear la clave ajena que es otro tipo de índice, key, llave o clave.

```
ALTER TABLE productos
  ADD INDEX(id);
```

Te paso todo el SQL para que puedas reproducir el ejemplo mínimo:

```
CREATE TABLE productos(
  id int
  );
CREATE TABLE descripción(
  id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  idproductos int
  );
ALTER TABLE productos
  ADD INDEX(id);
ALTER TABLE descripción
  ADD FOREIGN KEY(idproductos) REFERENCES productos(id)
  ON DELETE CASCADE
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
INSERT INTO productos VALUES (1),(2),(3);
INSERT INTO descripción VALUES (NULL,1),(NULL,2);
DELETE FROM productos WHERE id=1;
SELECT * FROM descripción;
```

Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios

Comment: Ahora cuando introduzco datos, me aparece el error 
.
'#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`inventario`.`#sql-1a98_654`, CONSTRAINT `#sql-1a98_654_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`idproductos`) REFERENCES `productos` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION)'

Al poner `idproductos` por defecto _null_ , vuelve a tener todos null

Comment: ¿Para qué los pones a NULL? Por favor, enséñame el INSERT

Comment: Y modifica la pregunta añadiendo los detalles de los comentarios:)